# c++ Collision Detection for a turning rectangle

Tags: c++, opengl

I have some collision detection working when my player hits an object. But this only works when my players x & y co-ordinates hit my marker (which is the centre of my character).

Would making a method returning a vector of all of the coordinates that the players texture cover work and what is the best way to implement this?

This is being done in c++ creating a top down game

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with turning. If not rotating you could read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/aabb/info.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, most simply is probably(depending on you use of classes etc).
This is the simplest, but no where near the best, or infact very good at all. This way means changing your "marker" to the bottom left of the rectangle.

```
void collisions()
{
    //check if the x-coord is between the furthest left and furthest right x coords
    if(rect.Getx() > someObject.Getx() && rect.Getx() < someObject.Getx() + someObject.GetWidth())
    {
        rect.SetMoveSpeed(0);
    }
    if(rect.Gety() > someObject.Gety() && rect.Gety() < someObject.Gety() + someObject.GetHeight())
    {
        rect.setMoveSpeed(0);
    }

}
```

You would then have to set the move speed to normal when it is not colliding. That could be done with an else after each if, setting the move speed again. This is a quick fix and is not recommended for use in a game you plan to distribute anywhere.

Comment: This is similar to what I already have. but the getY and getX is the middle of player so when the edges of the player collide with my objects it doesnt affect it, only when the middle (player co-ords)  collide

Comment: Yes, change them to the bottom right and left? what version of OpenGL are you using? The position is defined by you. Just get to the bottom left.